# Not able to send json tweets events to Kafka topic/producer using kafka command line

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-sandbox

I have created a python script `raw_tweets_stream.py` to stream twitter data using twitter api. The json data from twitter is pipped to kafka producer using the script below.

---

```
`python raw_tweets_stream.py | /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:2181 --topic raw_json_tweets`
```

---

`raw_json_tweets` is the kafka topic created for these tweets. The python script `raw_tweets_stream.py` runs just fine but it throws error while sending it to the kafka producer. I am using Hortonworks HDP 2.3.1 sandbox and I have made sure that the zookeeper and kafka are started.

---

`/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic raw_json_tweets`

```
Topic:raw_json_tweets      PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:
            Topic: raw_json_tweets     Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

Error:

```
[2016-08-25 22:36:26,212] ERROR Failed to send requests for topics raw_json_tweets with correlation ids in [57,64] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2016-08-25 22:36:26,213] ERROR Error in handling batch of 131 events (kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread)
kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:91)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:547)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
[2016-08-25 22:36:27,217] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 65 for topics [Set(json_tweets1)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,localhost,2181)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.read(CoreUtils.scala:193)
        at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive.readFrom(BoundedByteBufferReceive.scala:54)
        at kafka.network.Receive$class.readCompletely(Transmission.scala:56)
        at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive.readCompletely(BoundedByteBufferReceive.scala:29)
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:131)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:77)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:74)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:115)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.getBrokerPartitionInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:49)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$getPartitionListForTopic(DefaultEventHandler.scala:188)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$partitionAndCollate$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:152)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$partitionAndCollate$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:151)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.partitionAndCollate(DefaultEventHandler.scala:151)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:96)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:547)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
        at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
```

---

**Update: Solution**

---

1. Went to Ambari Services and changed the Kafka logs directory to `/tmp/kafka-logs`.
2. Modified the original script to include the correct port and hostname.

   `python raw_tweets_stream.py | /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667 --topic raw_json_tweets`
3. Verified that the events are sent to the kafka topic using console consumer.

   `/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh -zookeeper sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181 -topic raw_json_tweets -from-beginning`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're pointing the `--broker-list` at zookeeper (`2181`) instead you need to point at the kafka broker whose default port is `9092` or `6667` on Ambari.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Binary Nerd. I updated the kafka broker with the correct port 9092 but still throwing the error. Here is part of the error --> [2016-08-26 13:24:12,718] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(raw_json_tweets)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(BrokerEndPoint(0,localhost,9092))] failed (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler) .. java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

Comment: According to the Hortonworks documentation, if you're using Ambari the default port is `6667`, perhaps try that - https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.2/bk_secure-kafka-ambari/content/ch_secure-kafka-config-options.html

Comment: You are right. The correct port for hortonworks is 6667(also verified this going to ambari Services)  . Modified the script to include the correct port `6667` and full host name `sandbox.hortonworks.com`.. worked like a charm. `python raw_tweets_stream.py | /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667 --topic raw_json_tweets`